# Angular @Input array- how to reference different array object field names?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, components

I want to setup a reusable dropdown menu whereby I pass an array of objecs to the @Input of my dropdown component and then update some labels in it.

The array fields will be different each time. One array might have a `displayName` string field, while another array will have a string called `id` as the field I want to reference, for example.

I'm not sure how to reference these on a per instance basis.

#### Dropdown HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of content">
  <span class="button-label">{{item.whatever-the-field-is}}</span>
</ng-container>
```

#### Dropdown Component:

```
@Input() content: Array<any> = [];
```

#### Dropdown Instance:

```
<multi-button-dropdown [content]="(myArrayObservable$ | async)"></multi-button-dropdown>
```

#### Example Arrays:

```
users = [
  {
    id: 'afvnf102841-251',
    username: 'Joe Bloggs'
  }
  ...
]

members = [
  {
    displayName: 'Han Solo',
    location: 'Space'
  }
  ...
]
```

**Question:**

How do i setup the dropdown.html/component so that the `<span>` `{{item....}}` reference will be `displayName` for the members[] instance, `id` for the users[] instance and so on, passed in by another @Input value?

Comment: The example arrays are wrong. Probably you were trying to define array of objects instead.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that completely

Answer (score 1):

One quick way would be to use the `keyvalue` pipe inside the `*ngFor` to iterate over the object properties without knowing it's names.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of content">
  <span class="button-label" *ngFor="let prop of item | keyvalue">
    {{ prop.key }} - {{ prop.value }}
  </span>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can make a new interface which sets out the label value, and map the Observable array object fields to this value before passing it into the component:

```
this.dropdownUsers = users.map(user => (
  {
    label: user.displayName
  }
));

<multi-button-dropdown [content]="dropdownUsers"></multi-button-dropdown>
```